# trouble with jquery .empty()

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I am using jquery to populate a div with a table with data from a web service but I noticed that If I reloaded the page the div was not being over written but appended to. I looked up the jquery .empty() function but it does not seem to be working for me

here is a sample of my code:

The Div tag

```
<div id="AccountGrid" class="AccountGridHolder">

</div>
```

The Jquery that loads the function

```
 $(document).on('pagecontainershow', function (event,ui) {
                 GetAcount();
              });
```

The jquery Function

```
function GetAcount() {
    $('#AccountGrid').empty()
    var CompanyID = get_localstorage("CompanyID");
        source:
            {
                $.ajax({
                      crossDomain: true,
                      url: "https://webservice/methode",
                      type: "POST",
                      dataType: "json",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      data: "{ 'CompanyID' : '" + CompanyID + "'}",
                      dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                      success: function (data) {
                          var Table1 = '<fieldset><legend>Company Name</legend><table id="CompanyRow" class="AccountGrid" ><tr><td>';
                          Table1 = Table1 + data.d[0] + '</td></tr></table></feildset>';
                          $(".AccountGridHolder").append(Table1);
                      },
                      error: function (Error) {
                          console.log('CompanyID (fail) = ' + CompanyID);
                          console.log(Error.status);
                          console.log(Error.statusText);
                          console.log(Error.responseText);
                      }
                  });
              }
          }
```

can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Since you probably copied and pasted you need to correct the spelling for fieldset. The closing tag is misspelled.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is wrong. It should be `$('#AccountGrid')` if you want to match by id.

Comment: ah your right, but that didn't solve the problem. I will play around with it tomorrow and see if I can get this to work

Comment: What's happening now? Same exact thing or something different?

Comment: the exact same thing is happening still

Comment: using console.log() I can see that #AccountGrid is selecting the right element. its just .empty is not doing anything for some reason

Comment: Any particular reason you're labeling the code block with the `ajax` call? Not saying it's definitely related, but you never know. Doesn't look the label is doing you any favors, that's for sure--you never reference back to it.

Comment: sorry I confused, how would I do the ajax call to my web service without using the $ajax call? as far as I was aware this was the best way to call a web service.

Comment: I'm not telling you not to use the `ajax` call. I'm just saying it's curious that you've wrapped it in a labeled code block: `source: {...}`. May not be hurting you, but it is odd, and some browsers have (at least historically) not handled labeled blocks consistently with each other.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I have updated this whole ajax call now anyway as I have just read that success and error have been depreciated

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `append()` use `html()` it will replace the content of div.

```
$(".AccountGridHolder").html(Table1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".AccountGridHolder").empty();
$(".AccountGridHolder").append(Table1);
```

is equivalent to

```
$(".AccountGridHolder").html(Table1);
```

So why to write two lines instead of one ? Go for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure why but when I moved the empty() line it started to work... here is my code now

```
function GetAcount() {
            var CompanyID = get_localstorage("CompanyID");
        source:
            {
                $.ajax({
                      crossDomain: true,
                      url: "https://webservice/methode",
                      type: "POST",
                      dataType: "json",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      data: "{ 'CompanyID' : '" + CompanyID + "'}",
                      dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                      success: function (data) {
                          $('#AccountGrid').empty();
                          var Table1 = '<fieldset><legend>Company Name</legend><table id="CompanyRow" class="AccountGrid" ><tr><td>';
                          Table1 = Table1 + data.d[0] + '</td></tr></table></fieldset>';
                          $(".AccountGridHolder").append(Table1);
                      },
                      error: function (Error) {
                          console.log('CompanyID (fail) = ' + CompanyID);
                          console.log(Error.status);
                          console.log(Error.statusText);
                          console.log(Error.responseText);
                      }
                  });
              }
          }
```

I find this really odd because that would suggest the problem was that the div had not loaded but this code only executes after the 'pagecontainershow' event has fired

Answer (score -1):

Try using .html() instead of .append()

```
$(".AccountGridHolder").html(Table1);
```